# I want to update the subtotal by clicking plus minus(real time) Magento 2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I want to update my subtotal by clicking +/- without any loading. I am using javascript to change the values but it's loading to change values. Is there anyone to help me out for this issues. please show me the file path where I have to overwrite. Please help by realtime ajax minicart source code for Magento 2.
please check my attachment image below.[image]

Thanks

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96116/increment-and-decrement-qty-button-on-shopping-cart-page or http://surajviradiya.blogspot.sg/2015/09/add-increase-and-decrease-quantity.html

Comment: This code is for  Magento 1.9. I need it for Magento 2.1.1

Comment: This is only reference.